# how to add audio to picture?

Tags: javascript

**something like this**

For example sounds of dogs and horses or any animal in css or html.

I've alredy tried other websites but no luck.

Something that needs for().

Comment: You could use the `mouseenter' event and then use a function, which plays a sound. I don't think, that it would be possible with only css or html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the <AUDIO> tag. It has a JavaScript function `play()`. So you just need to run `play()` on a mouseenter event